# How can I turn off the LEDs on the front of my laptop(ASUS K501LX-NH52)?

Tags: laptop, led, asus-laptop

Is there a way to turn off the lights on the front of my laptop? My laptop: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834232753R. I am currently running a dual-boot of KDE Fedora and Windows 10.

If there is no way to turn it off in the BIOS can I can unplug the cord running to it? Here is a picture of it:

[image: Pic of LED]

Comment: Put black tape over them?

Answer (score 7):

On Linux check this directory.

```
/sys/class/leds/
```

If there are subdirectories, look inside for a file called `trigger`
Reading the `trigger` file will list the available LED control parameters, with the current one surrounded by brackets.

To change the trigger parameter, just write the name of the parameter to the `trigger` file.

Another file, `brightness` can be used to disable to LED as well. Writing `0` to `brightness` will shut off the LED that that particular subdirectory controls.

To disable all controllable LEDs as a test, you can try:

```
for led in /sys/class/leds/*;
do
  echo 0 | sudo tee ${led}/brightness
done
```

If you cannot control the LEDs this way, unplugging the board may be the only way.

Comment: The `sudo` won't work the way you think.

Comment: I tried the `echo` command but it didn't return anything. I found that `ls /sys/class/leds/` returns `asus::kbd_backlight  input3::numlock     mmc0::
input3::capslock     input3::scrolllock  phy0-led`

Comment: After playing with them I found that the file `/sys/class/leds/input3::capslock/brightness` would contain a number in this case 1. If I changed the number to 0 and saved the file the capslock light would turn off. However after looking in all of the files none seemed to contain anything for the battery or hard drive light(the cylinder). Any advice on what to do next or should I simply unplug it?

Answer (score 1):

If that board only has the LEDs on it, I'd imagine it's safe to unplug it. That's probably honestly the easiest way, otherwise you might have to write a bunch of custom code to do it. Just gently flip the black cover and the ribbon cable should come right out. If you wanted to be extra careful you could put a bit of electrical tape or unheated/unshrunk head shrink around the contacts on the cable - I would probably be reluctant to put electrical tape on it, because that tends to leave a gooey mess.

Comment: If unplugging is not an option just get some black electrical tape and put it over the LEDs, this will hide the lights while being completely invisible from the outside.